# Can't get anchor to dynamically resize control

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, anchor, dock

I have two controls in a groupbox ("Waveforms"). I would like them to dynamically resize also by height but can't get it to work. I've used left|top|right anchor for 1st control ("Left channel") and left|bottom|right anchor for 2nd ("Right channel").

Here is a [short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_baVj48xt4s) of problem.

How can I acomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your controls to share vertical space of the `GroupBox`, you can use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) or a [`SplitContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx).

By using a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) you can easily specify how the vertical space should be shared by controls. For example you can add two rows to the [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) and give them each 50% of the whole height.

By using a [`SplitContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx), the user can change the occupied heights of the controls at runtime.